# How to change the url of already opened chrome tab from internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, uri, wsh

I have a web application and this app works on IE browser and i want to open a chrome browser from IE and later change the tab URL. It is like window.open() but in Chrome. I found the way to open a chrome browser from IE but after i open it i can't reach it and change the URL. How to do it with js because as far as i know i can't access the client's pc. Is there any way to achieve this?

Here is a code to open chrome browser from IE with js;

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Run("Chrome {{URL}}");
```

But after that i can not access this window and change its url. I can't do this with java because java code works on the server side and i have to access the client's pc processes. And shell.Run() method always opens a new tab. But i want the existing tab URL to change.

I found below link but i guess this also requires to access the client's registry files. And still i can't see a way to change the existing chrome tab URL in this solution;

https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2015/05/how-to-launch-a-url-in-google-chrome/

I tried testing tools like selenium but these tools are also work on the server pc. I don't know if this can be done by vbscript also.

I am really stuck at this for weeks so any help will be appreciated.

Update:
The solution above could work actually. Creating a URI Scheme with registry files, but when i try the above solution, the URL parameter can not be passed and opens chrome main page not the URL. Could you provide a solution for this?

Comment: Is there anyone to answer this question? Or any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps with the *intWindowStyle* option set to 4 or 5?

See here: https://ss64.com/vb/run.html

Comment: Nothing happens actually.